# Java Tic-Tac-Toe, prints 3 boards

Tags: java, tic-tac-toe

I'm having a setback in the code for a Tic Tac Toe Java program. Every time I run it, the game board prints 3 times and o the second time, the X's all fill in a line saying that player X wins. I've been trying to figure it out, but I still can't find the problem going on with it. What I'm asking is, what is the main problem of the code printing out more than it needs to and to stop filling in the lines?

I hope I format this correctly.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TicTacToeWork {

    //Variable declaration.
    public static char[][] GameBoard = new char[3][3];
    public static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static int column, row;
    public static char PlayerTurn = 'X';

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        for (int i = 0; i > 3; i++) {

            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                GameBoard[i][j] = '_';
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Enter coordinates of row then column to choose your space.");
        Playing();
    }

    public static void Playing() {

        boolean PlayerPlaying = true;

        while (PlayerPlaying) {
            boolean playing = true;

            while (playing) {
                row = keyboard.nextInt() - 1;
                column = keyboard.nextInt() - 1;
                GameBoard[row][column] = PlayerTurn;

                if (EndGame(row, column)) {
                    playing = false;
                    System.out.println("Game over player " + PlayerTurn + " wins!");
                }
                BoardPrint();

                if (PlayerTurn == 'X') {
                    PlayerTurn = 'O';
                } else {
                    PlayerTurn = 'X';
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void BoardPrint() {

        //Print out the game board.
        for (int i = 0; i < GameBoard.length; i++) {
            for (int n = 0; n < 3; n++) {
                System.out.println();

                for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {

                    if (j == 0) {
                        System.out.print("| ");
                    }
                    System.out.print(GameBoard[i][j] + " | ");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static boolean EndGame(int RowMove, int ColumnMove) {

        //Deciding factors on who wins and ties.
        if (GameBoard[0][ColumnMove] == GameBoard[1][ColumnMove]
                && GameBoard[1][ColumnMove] == GameBoard[2][ColumnMove]) {
            return true;
        }
        if (GameBoard[RowMove][0] == GameBoard[1][RowMove]
                && GameBoard[RowMove][0] == GameBoard[RowMove][2]) {
            return true;
        }
        if (GameBoard[0][0] == GameBoard[1][1] && GameBoard[0][0] == GameBoard[2][2]
                && GameBoard[1][1] != '_') {
            return true;
        }
        if (GameBoard[0][2] == GameBoard[1][1] && GameBoard[0][2] == GameBoard[2][0]
                && GameBoard[1][1] != '_') {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question? We are not here to debug your code. Please read the help: http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 0):

Your BoardPrint method is all wrong.  You have to do something like this..

```
public static void BoardPrint() {
    System.out.println("-------------");

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        System.out.print("| ");

        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            System.out.print(GameBoard[i][j] + " | ");
        }
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("-------------");
    }
```

You are also going to have to redo your check for a win.

A little hint.. you are not using a Boolean method correctly.  This line `if(EndGame(row, column))` is saying if EndGame is true stop the game.  The way you have your method set up it is not doing the check correctly.  You would have to say "if not true" - so it would look like this `if(!EndGame(row, column))`  There are a couple of other errors but this should give you a good start on completing the project.